# Getting Oauth onexternallogincallback?error=access_denied on certain Google Accounts and not others

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, owin, google-oauth, google-authentication

Recently our Google Signin started failing (externallogincallback?error=access_denied) on certain client deployments of our MVC app.

The only variable seems to be the Google Account where the Client ID / secret was created. We have confirmed that the Google+ API is enabled and the Authorized JavaScript origins and Authorized redirect URIs are correct. We have duplicated behavior in development using the same  Client ID / secret and also went as far as adding the URLs and creating Client ID / secret in a different Google account and it works in the app when we update it with these new creds.

We use Azure and we are on version Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google 3.1.0. I tried to update to the latest 4.1.0 with no luck. Again, other clients are fine on 3.1.0.

Has anyone experienced and issue with one Google Account, but not another? I don't have an exact time this started but it has been in the last month or two. I don't recall having to do anything outside the consent screen, the credentials and enabling the API.

Answer (score 2):

Since Google plus has deprecated from January 2019 and owin google authentication middleware 3.1.0 get userinfos from google plus API then you must change userinfos endpoint to https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo

source: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/issues/251#issuecomment-449587635

```
        app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions()
        {
            ClientId = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("google:clientid"),
            ClientSecret = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("google:clientsecret"),
            UserInformationEndpoint = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo",
            BackchannelHttpHandler = new GoogleUserInfoRemapper(new WebRequestHandler())
        });



internal class GoogleUserInfoRemapper : DelegatingHandler
{
    public GoogleUserInfoRemapper(HttpMessageHandler innerHandler) : base(innerHandler) { }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

        if (!request.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri.Equals("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo"))
        {
            return response;
        }

        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        var text = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        JObject user = JObject.Parse(text);
        JObject legacyFormat = new JObject();

        JToken token;
        if (user.TryGetValue("id", out token))
        {
            legacyFormat["id"] = token;
        }
        if (user.TryGetValue("name", out token))
        {
            legacyFormat["displayName"] = token;
        }
        JToken given, family;
        if (user.TryGetValue("given_name", out given) && user.TryGetValue("family_name", out family))
        {
            var name = new JObject();
            name["givenName"] = given;
            name["familyName"] = family;
            legacyFormat["name"] = name;
        }
        if (user.TryGetValue("link", out token))
        {
            legacyFormat["url"] = token;
        }
        if (user.TryGetValue("email", out token))
        {
            var email = new JObject();
            email["value"] = token;
            legacyFormat["emails"] = new JArray(email);
        }
        if (user.TryGetValue("picture", out token))
        {
            var image = new JObject();
            image["url"] = token;
            legacyFormat["image"] = image;
        }

        text = legacyFormat.ToString();
        response.Content = new StringContent(text);
        return response;
    }
}
```